# Behavioural part in cuckoo analysis report empty

Tags: sandbox, malware, malware-detection, sandbox-solution

I analyzed a malware sample

SHA1 : 0bd0a280eb687c69b697d559d389e34d4fad02b2.

The result generated by cuckoo doesnt contain any information about Behavioral analysis. I analyzed the same malware on malwr.com and it's showing the behavioral part correctly with the file accesses, registry keys,mutexes. Link for malwr.com report(https://malwr.com/analysis/ZjA1OTExOWI5ZWIwNDZjMjkyN2Y5NWRmMzhlNWRhZmY/)

I am unable to figure out where the fault is. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried analyzing other files?

Answer (score 0):

one reason might be that the malware have virtual machine environment detector ability. i faced same problem when analysing: 1fb06a150c91059501b739708627a9c752d906aff211455248cecb755a5a5c6a

maybe cuckoo server uses some hardening vm for malwares, so they cant detect the fake environment. have a look at: [kernelmode](http://www.kernelmode.info/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3478&sid=3f37f2beb7ac942b91d311ab51ceb6c3)